# javascript remove last word in textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, cpu-word

Can anyone help me to remove last word from the text area and it will replace with some another word.

Example:

```
I like my dog
```

should become

```
I like my cat
```

The last word is not always dog.

I'll update my code here

```
    function KeyCheck(e) {

var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

switch(KeyID) {
    case 32:
        text2 = document.form1.box1.value;
        text2 = ReplaceLastWord(text2, "cat");
                alert(text2);
    }
}

function ReplaceLastWord(str, newStr) {
   return str.replace(/\w*$/, newStr);
}
```

I have put alert to check whether it's replaced or not

Comment: Is your problem how to access the contents of the textarea, or how to figure out what the last word is? Is it always the last word, or any use of the word? What's your expected output if the text is "Do you like my dog? I like my dog."

Comment: @nnnnnn He may need someone to like his textarea's dog...

Comment: The dog ate my textarea.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Do you like my dog? I like my cat

Comment: @jonny-king  I think you have got answer.. Your cat will be with you only to like.. You did not post any HTML or code except i like my dog and cat.. Please have a look at answers for your question and try to find whether it matches your requirement or not. Else try to post some HTML except cat and dog..

Comment: The dog ate my answer. @Johnny: From the comments, you say you want to do it when the spacebar is pressed, but what if the user presses ctrl-V or uses the context menu to paste in a space character? Same thing? What if the user moves the cursor to the middle of the sentence and starts typing - would you then _not_ replace "dog" because it's not at the end of the whole textarea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var str = 'I like my dog'; 
var newEndStr = 'cat'; 

function ReplaceLastWord(str, newStr) {
   return str.replace(/\w*$/, newStr);
}

console.log(ReplaceLastWord(str, newEndStr));
```

output:

```
I like my cat
```

Comment: Yes, this is a easy way to achieve the requirement. But if you can add spacebar event to replace the last string as he has mentioned in his question it will exactly matches his requirement. Like $(document).live('keydown',function(e){  //Here code to replace });

Answer (score 2):

You can search for the last space character and replace the text after it:

```
text = text.replace(/\w+$/, '');
text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(' ')) + ' foobar';
```

The first line strips all trailing spaces.

---

You can bind a `onkeydown` event to your `textarea`. If `e.keyCode || e.which` is equal to the space bar code (no idea what it is), pass the contents of the textarea through this function:

```
function getLastWord(text) {
  temp = text.replace(/\w+$/, '');

  return temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf(' '), temp.length - 1)
}
```

Then check if the last word is `dog`. *Now* you can replace the last word.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that needed to be replaced by pressing space bar..

like i'll type

I like my dog

and then press space bar then it needs to be changed to

I like my cat

so there is new space creating because of pressing space bar.

Comment: But there is a space in between every one of those words, so pressing the spacebar would make your string `cat cat cat cat`.

Comment: I think he means to do the replacement only if the last word is some predefined word ("dog", in his example), in which case you could probably do `text.replace(/\sdog$/, ' cat')`. @Johnny - how about you update your question to say what you really mean then?

Comment: nnnnnn - No that word shouldn't be predefined word.

@Blender - Thanks a lot for your code but in that first line all the things will cleared not even spaces...but i needs is

Someone type "I like my dog" in the text area and press spacebar that text should become "I like my cat" like that.once they press the spacebar it's creating another space after the word dog and the script replace like "I like my dogcat" like that.

Any help ?

Comment: @Blender - I have tried but that out put is null what is the wrong ?

Comment: By "predefined" I mean a word that was somehow specified in advance (perhaps in a variable), as compared to always replacing the last word no matter what it is.